# How to resolve problem with back-face culling and export it to a game engine?

Tags: mesh, uv, normals

I would like to know how to fix the problem with "back-face culling", check this photo.

[image]

In my 3D viewport you can see the right window in Unity has a problem, you can as spectator see the inside of the pipe, however in front view (left window in the picture) the interior faces are ok .

So my first steps in Blender were

1. Check the display to "GLSL" (Blender Internal)
2. Go into Edit Mode and flip the normals of all the mesh (press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Flip Normals* on all mesh objects).
3. Once I've flipped all the normals I activate the option *Back-face Culling* in the <kbd>N</kbd> panel
4. Apply the transformation .
5. Unwrap the model (check marked seams if possible and space for
   texture bleeding)
6. Export in FBX/OBJ files to the game engine.

I would like to know how to fix back-face culling for cylinders objects.

Comment: You should not blindly be flipping normals, you shouls instead make them consistent instead with `Ctrl+N`

Comment: "control  + n"  instead of using "w" for flpped the normals?

Comment: `Ctrl+N`In *Edit Mode* > *Make Normals Consistent*

Comment: for this case, a cylinder , should I select all the faces to flipped? or just chosen areas, In this model I ve use "A" keyboard to select all the faces and then...well "control + N " as you said before.

Comment: That should about do it. *Make Normals Consistent* operator works best on a whole mesh at once, provided the mesh is manifold and consistently modeled

Comment: can I chose some parts of the model? I mean , can I chose an interior faces for the cyclinders and change the normals? and the outside faces of the cylinders leave with the curren and default projection ?

Comment: This is because your tube is a plane, single faces. add a solidify modifier so it has faces to both sides. Apparently  you can turn backface culling off in unity, but it causes bad lighting or something like that

Comment: for newbs like me it's shift-n in edit mode. Also, first, you need to pick your object in the scene collection explorer (the one with all the objects listed by name) then press a to select all the faces, then select shift-n. Or, you can go to the menu and click mesh -> normals -> recalculate outside after selecting all the faces you want. Hope I didn't just further confuse anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Blender's show back faces option is just for viewport purposes and doesn't effect export. The easiest solution is to duplicate the faces of your pipe, flip the normals on the copy, and keep both overlaid. Alternatively you can find or make a Unity shader that shows back faces.

Comment: Just to add: Showing backfaces in Unity is better performance, but the real issue is if you need different lighting for both sides, in which case a two-sided mesh is better.  A one-sided no-cull mesh is going to show the same lighting on both sides.